# L^1-Fourier Transform is not bounded below

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know that $\mathcal{F}_1:{\rm L}^1(\mathbb{R})\to {\rm C}_0(\mathbb{R})$ is not bounded below. I also know that since in ${\rm L}^2$ the operator is actually a diagonalizable unitary, I should not try to find a proof using such functions.

So, I'm trying to show, if possible, explicitly, that there are functions $f\in{\rm L}^1$ such that $\lVert f\rVert_{{\rm L}^1}=1$ althogh $\lVert\hat{f}\rVert_{\infty}<\varepsilon$.

Is such a thing even possible? I tried using every "known" function I'm familiar with, and got completely lost.

Comment: Equivalently, with $n = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, you are looking for $g_n = \hat{f}_n$ such that
$$
\|g_n\|_{L^\infty} = 1 \ \text{ and } \ \|\hat{g}_n\|_{L^1} = n
$$
so I you could try to find a sequence approaching $g = \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty]}$ since it fourier transform is $1/ix$ which is not in $L^1$

Comment: @LL3.14 Perhaps the most explicit is $\frac1{x-i/n}-\frac1{x-1-i/n}$